# Flash sum total loosing trailing zeros

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a sum that works out any chosen percentage discount (percentage1.text) of a selected product (status2_txt.text). I've managed to get the value to display just 2 decimal points but it looses its trailing zeros, pulling my hair out!

This is what I currently have:

```
total_btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getTotal3);

function getTotal3(e:MouseEvent):void {
     discount1.text = String( Number(status2_txt.text) / Number(100) *     Number(percentage1.text));
    discount1.text = int((discount1.text)*100)/100;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help with this!
Thanks

Comment: What output you want to receive and what you receive actually?

Comment: if I put 26.00 (status2_txt.text) and 10% (percentage1.text) I get '2.6' rather than '2.60' - missing the zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try function [toFixed](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed()).

```
var ret:Number = Number(status2_txt.text) / 100 * Number(percentage1.text);
discount1.text = ret.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: toFixed return a String so casting to String is irrelevant.